# HTML5 javascript animation compared to the usual infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, html, animation

How does HTML5 javascript sprite animation works compared to the usual inifnite loop in C++ ? It doesn't appear to be a main infinite loop in animated Javascript programs. Is there a callback function that is called at regular intervals by the browser ?

I'm talking about javascript interactive animation like for a browser game.

Comment: There are many different ways to animate something in an HTML5 browser.  What exact type of animation are you talking about when you say "HTML5 javascript sprite animation"?  There are 100% CSS3 animations.  There are 100% Javascript animations.  There are GIF animations.  They all work differently.  Which are you asking about?

Comment: @jfriend00 100%javascript I'm talking about interactive animation like for a browser game

Comment: by help of a timer, a function keeps running in particular intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

100% Javascript animations use either recurring timers (for example, call my code every 50ms) or use [`window.requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) to get repeatedly called.  In either case, the main message processing is allowed to be interwoven with repeated animation function calls which allows the application to remain interactive (e.g. processing user input events) while the animation is running.

Keep in mind that in a modern browser, it is also possible to use a combination of Javascript to direct the animations and change the course of animations in response to user input, but to use CSS3 animation directives to actually carry out and run the animations.  In this case, it is the browser's own native code that is drawing the animation frames themselves and exactly how this is done is up to the internal implementation of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont use a canvas and working with html elements you should use a css3 animation. For example - [Animation.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)